# Problem execution scope org-babel in shell on windows 8

Tags: org-babel, microsoft-windows, shell-command

I just discovered that in order to run a sequence of shell commands under the same scope (same shell session) I have to add a hash at the end of the line.

**Example**

When I try to run the following two lines I get the wrong list of files. I get the files located in the directory of the org file from where this code block is executed.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/path
ls
#+END_SRC
```

However, everything works fine if I pack a hash symbol at the end of the first line.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/path #
ls
#+END_SRC
```

I find this really annoying since this could be very dangerous in case a writing operation is performed and the hash is forgotten.

**Questions**

1- Am I overinterpreting the effect of the (lack of the) hash?

2- Is there something I can do to avoid the necessity of putting the hash at the end of each line of code?

**Note**

I am using Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) with built-in org (v 8.2.10). on windows 8.1. PathToUser/libexec/emacs/25.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe

I am almost new to emacs in windows since I have been mainly working with linux before and never encounter such a problem.